# Animation during saving process

Tags: vb.net

I have an application that takes quite long to save the data as it has to write over intranet.
I want to run an animation showing that saving is in progress.  How to do it?
Any code examples?

Thanks
Furqan

Answer (score 1):

Try to use Tasks:

```
Imports System.Threading.Tasks
```

...

```
Dim task As New Task(Save, Nothing)
task.ContinueWith(StopAnimation)
StartAnimation()
task.Start()
```

Where Save, StartAnimation and StopAnimation is your actions/methods.

Comment: It says .Tasks does not have any public member

Comment: There is no Task class in .net 3.5. You could use [Threads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(SYSTEM.THREADING.THREAD);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK%2cVERSION%3dV3.5%22);k(DevLang-CSHARP)&rd=true") and [SynchronizationContext](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/457237/run-code-on-ui-thread-without-control-object-present") in this case. You also can use [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx).